# Adding values from SQLite table to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite

I have a SQLite table in my app, and i would like to take the values from the table, put them in a json object and send them to my server. The  problem is i do not know how to handle the data. I would like to have add inside the JSONObject the values from each column as a List and I Would also like to put tags on the data. Basically I would like to have a BasicNameValuePair structure but ot be able to add lists on it. Basically i would something like this:

```
[tag]->[aNAME]
[columnA]->[dataA,dataA,...,dataA]
[columnB]->[dataB,dataB,...,dataB]
```

Is this possible??

Comment: i tried similar to that [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16833235/creating-json-objects-from-sqlite-database/16833566#16833566) change according to your req.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [jackon](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) for parsing json... it is quite easy, take a look.